# Looking for Apollo Flight Control Hardware Blueprints (such as RHC, THC and COAS)

Tags: apollo-program, crewed-spaceflight, design, engineering, flight-control

I've been looking to build replicas of Apollo flight control hardware such as RHC, THC, ACA, TTCA and COAS, and am looking for detailed engineering drawings that show dimensions and internal mechanisms. Are there any surviving drawings from Honeywell, Autonetics/North American Aviation or elsewhere?

Luckily there are many pictures of the actual objects and also I understand the News Reference and Systems Handbook have reasonably detailed diagrams showing the operation of these hardware. But blueprints would be nice if there are any.

Looking for something like [this for dimensions](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aft7lw1jx28a5sy/AADFbMvFzkCGSTB-acHLTHDua?dl=0&preview=MASON%20flightgrips.pdf.pdf) and [this for the internal mechanism](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080004314/downloads/20080004314.pdf).

---

pic of RHC internal

[image]

image source:[Historic Space Systems](https://space1.com/Artifacts/Apollo_Artifacts/Rotation_Control_Inside/rotation_control_inside.html)

---

- RHC = Rotational Hand Controller (CSM)
- THC = Translation Hand Controller (CSM)
- ACA = Attitude Controller Assembly (LM)
- TTCA = Thrust/Translation Controller Assembly (LM)
- COAS = Crewman Optical Alignment Sight

---

Also, if you know of any technical drawings of flight control hardware for other crewed spacecraft, I would be very grateful.